# Why flash embeded in flex mobile project runs slowly on iPad but not in simulator?

Tags: flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

Following is the line of code which embeds the flash swf file. It runs as original swf file on simulator but not great in iPad2. The speed of the animation decreases and animation breaks while running on iPad2.

Answer (score 0):

Ravi,

The simulator which you're using is not an iOS simulator. That's just a flash player. And in the iPad it installs the flash player and on that it runs the software. So it runs slower.

Lets how much adobe can prove them. Its a great initiative by them. Hope for the best!

Regards,
Sanket

Comment: is there any other solutions to this problem?

Comment: If you want performance then better use native tools rather than a third party alternative.